# Различные результаты вывода на CodeForces и на ПК

Tags: c++

В общем, решаю я на Codeforces задачи из архива. Написал решение для http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/614/B. 
Вот оно:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
string put_zero(int amount);
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string t[n];
    string result = "1";
    bool check,doIt=true,zero;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> t[i];
        if(t[i]=="0") {
            cout << "0";
            return 0;
        }
        if(t[i]=="1") continue;
        if(!check) {
            for(string::iterator it =t[i].begin(); it!=t[i].end();it++ ) {
                if((*it!='0' && *it != '1' && *it != '\0') || t[i]=="11" ) {
                    result.erase(0,1);
                    result = t[i] + result;
                    check=true;
                    doIt=false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if(doIt) {
            result = result + put_zero(count(t[i].begin(),t[i].end(),'0'));


        }

            doIt=true;
    }

    cout << result;

}
string put_zero(int amount)  {
    string toReturn = "";
    for(int x =0; x < amount;x++) {
        toReturn = toReturn + "0";
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Завалилось на первом же тесте.

3

5 10 1

Если всё правильно, то должно получиться 50. Но у меня выводит 10.
При этом при аналогичной проверки с вводом уже с моего компьютера ответ получается абсолютно верный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я переписал решение уже дважды, в чём может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Не специалист по Си, возможно, упускаю какую-то тонкость, но не вижу, где у Вас инициализируется `check`,

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема состоит в том, что переменная `bool check` не инициализируется. У простых встроенных типов при объявлении переменной на стеке очистка выделенной памяти не производится, поэтому в переменной оказывается непредсказуемое значение. В данном случае нулевое значение будет воспринято как `false`, а ненулевое - как `true`. Вероятно, на локальном компьютере программа компилируется в `debug`-режиме, когда часто многие блоки памяти зануляются, или же просто везёт и `check` попадает в нулевую область. Компилятор тестирующей системы работает, вероятно, в `release`-режиме, когда всё нацелено на оптимальность и уж явно не будет очистки стека без запроса.

Для того, чтобы исправить ошибку, достаточно просто инициализировать переменную при объявлении:

```
bool check = false;
```

(Кстати, переменная `bool zero` у Вас вообще не используется и, следовательно, её можно удалить.)

Вы легко можете проверить, что проблема была именно в этой переменной, задав ей другое значение - `true`. После этого программа начнёт выводить `10`, как и система тестирования.